# Necessary to have non-hd file?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing for iPhone 4 retina display using Cocos2d.

Well, I enabled retina display, and I have only put -hd graphics in my project. But when I run the project, it tells me that the -hd files are not found!

Then, I, for the sake of testing, put non-hd versions in the project. And apparently I don't get the error anymore.

This is puzzling. Does it mean I am forced to have -hd and non-hd versions in all my retina-enabled projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you change the implementation of `CCFileUtils`, that is correct. It will constantly warn you that you are missing files.

Comment: Ah well. Thank you. But wouldn't that be some kind of bug? Because, heck, what if I am *only* deploying for iPhone 4?

Comment: Change CCFileUtils? :P Cocos2D is tries to be compatible with all of the ios versions at the minutes. I long for the day where file.png is the normal and file-sd.png is used for providing and sd file without having to modify libraries.